If there is a reaction to the normal force, then why don’t we consider that in most cases?
Imagine there is a box of mass $m$ kept on a table. Now, there is a force $mg$ acting on the table due to the pull of the Earth, and the box pulled the Earth as a part of the action-reaction pair. Now, since the table applies a normal force upward on the block, according to Newton’s third law, there should also be a reaction to the normal by the box on the table. So, the net forces acting on the table by the box are $mg$ + the reaction of the normal force, but we say that only $mg$ acts. What happens to the reaction of the normal? I know there have been a lot of questions asked about this, but none of them answered my question. If someone gives me a table saying that can hold anything up to $1 \ \text{kg}$, does that mean I can only put a maximum $1/2 \, \text{kg}$ object considering the normal reaction?

$mg$ is the reaction to the normal force.

@paulina No, "reaction" forces are always the same type of forces as "action" forces. The reaction force to the force of gravity acting on the block is a force of gravity that the block exerts on the earth. The reaction to the normal force the table pushes up on the block is the normal force that the block exerts on the table. A good test is if you can get rid of one force but not the other then they were not an action/reaction pair. For example, if you push the block off the table the moment they are no longer in contact the normal force disappears but the force of gravity remains.

I don't think any answer pointed this out: in your description of the setup, you say there is a force mg acting on the table. However, this force acts on the box!

@M.Enns: Very insightful! I think it is a problem that "normal forces" in educational texts seem to be treated as something "handwaved" into existence without describing their actual cause (the electromagnetic force, according to Wikipedia). Keeping in mind that the electrons in both objects are interacting, it is easier to understand that objects "pushing down" on the object beneath them does that not by gravity or "weight" directly, but with their electrons!

@M.Enns You misunderstand what I think paulina meant. The question states that the box exerts on the table "mg + the reaction of the normal force". These forces are in fact one and the same.

Regardless of the precise physics involved, when we say that the table can hold up to 1kg, we've already taken these things into account, so you don't need to halve it.

So I am somewhat thrown off by your setup here. I think you are saying,

When the Earth pulls on a liter of water near the surface, it exerts a ~10 N force on the ~1 kg of water.
This also means that the water is pulling up on the Earth with a matching upward 10 N force.
If the water is at rest on a table, this means the table experiences the 10N force twice, once from the bottom where it's holding down the Earth, once from the top where it's holding up the box.

But, you could also be confused by something different, saying,

When the 10 N force acts on the water, it has to “go somewhere”, and it goes into the table, right?
But then that 10 N force is from gravity, but there is another 10 N force, the normal force of the table resisting the water, and this also generates a different force, not a gravitational force but a contact force, right?
So then aren't there two 10 N forces on the table, one of which is gravitational, one of which is contact —Isn’t that 20 N of force overall?

I’ll address both of these, but I hope you read both, not just the one that applies to you, because it's maybe helpful when you're trying to generate new pathways in your head to re-tread the parts you ‘already know.’
Doesn't the water pull up on the Earth?
So if the first situation is your question, I would say “you are exactly right,” and I would point you to Newton’s first law. Newton's first law says that if an object is either standing still, or moving with constant speed in a straight line, then it is in a state of force balance. (Newton's second law then defines forces as dispositions to deviate from this balanced state.) We can see that the table is not crashing through the floor or flying into the sky, it is stationary: this means we know the forces acting on it all sum to zero. And if there are two forces on it, this can get slightly confusing as they will be “equal and opposite”, but not due to the Third Law—rather they just happen to  have balanced out that way. In fact this is a key part of what a normal force even is.
In this case the table actually experiences three forces that balance,  and I think you are confused because you only have one $m$. The correct analysis is that the water has mass $m$, the table has mass big $M$. So if it’s a ~25 kg table then it experiences a -10 N force from the water bottle, pushing it down, a -250 N force from gravity, also pushing it down, and a normal force from the floor that keeps it in equilibrium, which must be +260 N to keep everything in force balance.
This is what I mean by force-balance being “part of what it means to be a normal force.” A normal force is a constraint force, the constraint here is that the floor joists in the building have not broken: and because they are still solid, that floor will supply whatever force is necessary (up to that breaking force threshold), to constrain the motion to not go through the floor. So the constraint is “this object, the floor, will remain in force-balance until you apply a force greater than the breaking force to it, and it will push normal to its surface to prevent you from occupying its space.” And that's what the normal force is.
And once we clarify all of that, then we come to your last question, which is just to say, “when we advertise the table as holding ‘up to 75kg,’ what we mean is that it will break under the pressures generated by a -750 N force on the surface, plus a + 1000 N force on the legs from the floor. We could have done the load tests on a ‘vomit comet’ plane that provides periods of weightlessness and double-weight in the cabin, those tests could have given all manner of other readings, but we just did the load testing on the surface of the Earth, and everybody expects that.
Doesn't the force balance double the force?
This is the more interesting confusion. The answer is that the action-reaction force pairs of Newton is how the force goes somewhere else in the first place, so you're counting the same force twice.
So the force of gravity on the water doesn't ‘have to go’ anywhere! It can just be unbalanced, in which case the water will accelerate downwards. If you throw the water into the air, it will describe a parabolic arc due to this unbalanced force.
When the water stops on the table, it first experiences an opposite imbalance (the constraint force has to cancel out its downward momentum) and then attains a state of force-balance. In this state of force balance (First Law), the upward force from the table equals the downward force of gravity, and the reaction force (Third Law) from that first-law normal force, “communicates” the gravity force from the water into the table, if you like.
So the interesting thing about this misunderstanding is that you have built up a folksy intuitive way of parsing the world, and you have been given a dry physical description of the same, and instead of recognizing that this is how the physics encodes your intuition, you have assumed that both are separately true, and the physics is describing something you hadn't thought of before. But that's precisely wrong, it's not two separate things, it's all the one thing.
In the mathematics, the force of gravity on the water, never acts on anything else. It only acts on the water. The water can act with other forces on other things, those other forces might sometimes have the same magnitude as gravity, or might sometimes point in the opposite direction. The mathematics doesn't care, it doesn't draw a logical connection between them. Newton's Third Law does draw a connection between force pairs, but those always act on separate objects, they will never both act on the same object.
But, we get this folksy sense of “the gravity force from the water is felt by the table,” precisely because the table didn't break under the weight of the water and enforced its constraint. To enforce that constraint, it pushed normal to its surface, on the water—more precisely on all of the places where the water tried to penetrate that surface. And because it pushed upward to enforce its boundary, it experienced a third law reaction pair which pushed it down, this is precisely how the weight of the water “is felt by the table.”
In the mathematics, the table feels its own gravitational force $gM$, but it doesn't know anything about $gm$, because it is not the water. The water tries to go through it, the table supplies whatever force (up to a threshold) needed to get the water to stop passing through it. At equilibrium that happens to be $gm$ but the table doesn't know if this is due to gravity vs. say a stream of water pouring into the bottle needing its downward momentum canceled vs. say an electric charge placed on the water moleculew being repelled from a like charge above them. The table doesn't know why, it doesn't feel anybody’s gravity other than its own, it's just maintaining its boundaries.

Thanks for clarifying.That helps.

You missunderstand Newton's third law because the terminology of action and reaction is pretty misleading and implies that one force causes another, which is simply not true. You are better off just forgetting these terms.
Newton's third law does not state that a force always generates another force which is opposite but equal in magnitude. Instead, Newton's third law states that an interaction between two physical objects always manifests as a pair of forces - one force acting on the first object and another force, opposite but equal in magnitude to the first force, acting on the second object. The first force does not cause the second force, nor does the second force cause the first force. Instead the two forces always appear simultaneously, together as a pair.

You are mixing things a bit. There are two interactions with the box:

the gravitational interaction with the box and the earth. This one has a gravitational force $mg$ downwards on the box, and a 3rd law gravitational reaction force $mg$ upwards on the earth.

the contact interaction with the box and the table. This is a normal contact force $N$ upwards on the box, and a 3rd law contact reaction force $N$ downwards on the table.


This is all that the 3rd law says. There is not any general relationship between $N$ and $mg$.
However, in the specific case that the box is stationary on the table we can invoke the 2nd law to obtain $N-mg=0$. However, that equality is a consequence of the 2nd law, not the 3rd

But why don’t we consider the reaction pair of the normal ? Why do we say that the force acting on the tabke is only “mg”

@AdityaPradhan we do consider the reaction pair of the normal force. That is my point 2.

You're right about the reaction force that the block will exert on the table. This reaction force is equal to the force exerted by the table on the block. So if equilibrium exists, we can say that R = mg (R - reaction, m - mass of block).
We do consider this reaction force.
The forces acting on the table will be the normal force exerted by the ground on the table (upwards, present at the contact points (or legs of the table)), weight of the table (downwards) and normal by block on the table (downward). If the table is at rest, it indicates that the upward and downward forces cancel each other. *NOTE: You don't have to consider the weight of the block in the FBD of the table because it is the force that the earth exerts on the block. In the free body diagrams we consider the forces acting on the body. So in the FBD of the table, we consider the forces acting on the table. *
And the answer to the latter part of your question:
No, it doesn't mean that. It simply means that you can put a block of  1 kg on the table and the table will be able to withstand that. The reaction of the block on the table now will be 9.8 N. As a result to keep the table in equilibrium, the normal reaction by the earth on the legs of the table will change. Again equilibrium is maintained.
Hope it helps!


So, the net forces acting on the table by the box are mg + the reaction of the normal force, but we say that only mg acts. What happens to the reaction of the normal?

Your mistake is in thinking that the mg force and the reaction to the normal force are different forces. The "mg force" (the one exerted on the table), in fact, is the reaction to the normal force. I think your point of confusion is that the texts you read are taking a common shortcut and didn't draw enough attention to the existence of that shortcut.
Without the shortcut, the reasoning to arrive at the force of mg being exerted on the table goes like this:

The force of gravity exerted by the Earth on the box is directed downward and has magnitude mg. The reaction to that force, exerted by the box on the Earth, affects something that is outside the scope of the calculation and can therefore be ignored.
The calculation is for a static situation, which implies that the net force on the box is 0. The only forces acting on the box are gravity and the normal force exerted by the table on the box. Therefore, the normal force acting on the box must be the exact opposite of the force of gravity, directed upward with magnitude mg.
The reaction to the above-mentioned normal force is the normal force of the box on the table. As per Newton's third law, it has equal magnitude and opposite direction: directed downward with magnitude mg.
The force exerted by the box on the table is therefore a downward force with magnitude mg.

The shortcut is just noting that the magnitude of mg carries through all these reasoning steps unchanged, and the changes of direction are two negations that cancel each other out. Therefore, if you recognize that a situation matches the pattern that these steps rely on, then you can skip directly from step 1 (gravity on the box is mg downward) to step 4 (force by box on table is mg downward).
The reaction force you ask about is not ignored, but rather is the mg force itself. The texts you've read just didn't call out its identity as that reaction force.

Then what is the normal force of the earth/ground/floor acting on the table?  (mass of box + mass of table) * g ?

@jarlemag Yes. It counteracts the combination of gravity on the table and the box's normal force on the table.

Perhaps it can help you to consider a series of masses $m_1, m_2, m_3, \dots , m_n$ stacked on top of one another and all being at rest, so that the system doesn't accelerate.
If we write the equations describing equilibrium for each mass, with mass $1$ being on top and $n$ at the bottom:
\begin{align*}
m_1: &&   m_1g\color{red}{-N_{2,1}}&=0 \\
m_2: &&  m_2g\color{red}{+N_{2,1}}\color{blue}{-N_{3,2}} &= 0\\
m_3: &&  m_3g\color{blue}{+N_{3,2}}-N_{4,3} &= 0 \\
\dots \\
\dots \\
m_{n-1}: && m_{n-1} g+N_{n-1,n-2}\color{magenta}{-N_{n,n-1}}&=0 \\
m_n: && m_n g\color{magenta}{+N_{n,n-1}}-N_{\text{earth}} &= 0
\end{align*}
Where I've color coded action reaction pairs, for example the normal force of mass $2$ on $1$ is $\color{red}{-N_{2,1}}$, the negative sign indicates it is acting upwards on $m_1$, and its reaction pair appears in the equation for $m_2$ and is equal to $\color{red}{+N_{2,1}}$ indicating it is acting downwards on $m_2$, etc.
If we sum up all these equations together, the action reaction pairs cancel in pairs, and we find that:
$$ m_1g+m_2g+m_3g+\dots+m_n g - N_{\text{earth}} = 0 $$
Which is just saying that a larger object of mass $M=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i$ is sitting stationary on the earth. Where exactly we draw the line and say "this is earth" or "this is the floor" is entirely up to us and chosen according to the requirement of the analysis we're making.
Notice that the interaction between each pair of masses in our system manifests itself as an action/reaction pair. The reaction pairs of the gravitational forces do not appear here, because we didn't write an equation for the earth itself, as it is irrelevant to this analysis. However if we did, one of the terms in it would be:
$$-Mg= -\sum_{i=1}^n m_i g$$
Which would account for the upward force the total mass pulls on the earth with.
More to your point however, in your example, if we take $m_1$ to be the box and $m_2$ to be the table we'll just get, for the box:
$$ m_1g - N_{2,1} = 0$$
and for the table:
$$ m_2g + N_{2,1} - N_{\text{earth}} = 0$$
Which implies
$$ m_1g + m_2g - N_{\text{earth}} = 0$$
So you see that the total force acting on the table is still $0$ as expected (since it is at equilibrium).
Also, you can see from the equation for $m_2$ (the table) that there's no problem in accounting for the reaction pair of the box on the table.

It sounds like you're thinking that the box exerts two different forces on the table, but your "two different forces" are actually two different descriptions of the same force.
The box doesn't exert a force on the table due to its weight in addition to another force on the table as the reaction to the normal force. Rather, the force that the box exerts on the table due to its weight is the reaction to the normal force.
Specifically, the forces involved here (ignoring interactions between the table and the Earth) are

the gravitational pull of the box on the Earth,
the gravitational pull of the Earth on the box,
the normal force exerted by the table on the box, and
the normal force exerted by the box on the table.

Forces 1 and 2 are action–reaction pairs, as are forces 3 and 4. Only one of these forces acts on the table, which is force 4, and force 4 is caused by force 2.
